# Enumerating camera roll pictures throws invalidoperationexception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

The below code throws invalidOperationException but only if the debugger is detached. The code targets 7.1 and from time to time users are reporting issues. This is the first time I can repro this issue on a windows phone 8 device but only when I detach the debugger. When the debugger is attached the code runs perfectly fine. The issue is not a consistent repro. In the analytics I saw small percentage of the users facing this issue. Any idea what’s happening here?

```
       PictureAlbum localRoll = media.GetCameraRoll();
       foreach (Picture pic in localRoll.Pictures) // exception here
       {

       }


        public PictureAlbum GetCameraRoll()
        {
        // Work around for known bug in the media framework.  Hits the static constructors
        // so the user does not need to go to the picture hub first.
        MediaPlayer.Queue.ToString();

        MediaLibrary ml = null;
        PictureAlbum cameraRoll = null;

        foreach (MediaSource source in MediaSource.GetAvailableMediaSources())
        {
            if (source.MediaSourceType == MediaSourceType.LocalDevice)
            {
                ml = new MediaLibrary(source);

                PictureAlbumCollection allAlbums = ml.RootPictureAlbum.Albums;

                foreach (PictureAlbum album in allAlbums)
                {
                    if (album.Name == "Camera Roll")
                    {
                        cameraRoll = album;
                        return cameraRoll;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

System.InvalidOperationException: An unexpected error has occurred.
at
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibraryEnumerator'1.System.Collection.Ienumerator'1.get_Item(Int32 index)

Comment: It is not null in the repro case.

Answer (score 2):

Very strange but works. Calling OrderBy first on the pictures doesn't throw exception.

```
                var a = localRoll.Pictures;

                foreach (Picture pic in a.OrderBy(x=>x.Date))
                {

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if `localRoll` and `localRoll.Pictures != null` and `localRoll.Pictures.Count > 0` because its possible that some phones have 0 pictures and the code is trying to iterate over a `null` collection.

```
   PictureAlbum localRoll = media.GetCameraRoll();
   if(localRoll != null)
   {
      if(localRoll.Pictures != null)
      {
          if(localRoll.Pictures.Count > 0)
          {
             foreach (Picture pic in localRoll.Pictures)
             {

             }
          }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Count is null and has hundreds of items.